# Asymptotics of integral - logarithm and cosine

Tags: integration, trigonometry, logarithms, fermi-dirac-integral

I have a parameter $\beta\geq 0$ and the following integral
\begin{equation}
I(\beta)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}k}{2\pi}\, \ln(1+e^{-\beta \cos k})
\end{equation}
And I'm trying to figure out the asymptotic for $\beta \rightarrow 0$ and  $\beta$ very large.

The first seems easy using a Taylor expansion, yet the second one is a bit more complicated because of the sign of $\cos(k)$ changing within the interval of integration.

Comment: Are you familiar with Fourier Analysis?

Comment: what exaclty have you ried? a short esimate shows that integral should be asymptotic to $\beta$ for large values of this parameter